# How to get total items from shopping cart

Tags: python, python-3.x

So, I have a shopping cart like so

```
shopping_cart = [("pear",1), ("orange", 1), ("apple",2), ("tomatoes",2), ("yoghurt",3)]
```

The amount is the number after the name.
I am looking to get the total amount of items bought by the customer.
to list the items and their amount I have:

```
for i in shopping_cart:
      print(f"{i[0]} x{i[1]} @  £{prices[i[0]]}")
```

I am looking to get the total quantity and store it in a variable called `total_items`

Comment: What have you tried to get the total quantity? In every iteration, `i[1]` gives you the number of items. Make a variable to keep track of the total items. For every element of your shopping cart, add its quantity to the total.

Comment: `len(shopping_cart)` gives you the number of unique items and `sum([elt[1] for elt in shopping_cart])` gives you the total number of items.

Answer (score 0):

You're better of storing shopping_cart in a dictionary and looping through the values

Here's the code:

```
shopping_cart = {
    "pear": 1,
    "orange": 1,
    "apple": 2,
    "tomatoes": 2,
    "yoghurt": 3,
}

total_fruit = 0
for i in shopping_cart.values():
    total_fruit += i

print(total_fruit)

OUTPUT = 9
```

Comment: Why are they better off storing `shopping_cart` as a dictionary? Don't just make statements -- justify them.

Comment: Sure, a dictionary holds key:value pairs and are far easier to access that whatever has been created by poster.

Comment: [Edit] that into your answer. _Why_ are they far easier to access? In what situation might you need to access a specific item? (hint: lookup/change the quantity of a specific item) There are situations where you might have to make do with a list of "tuples" -- e.g. if you queried a database. From [answer]: _"Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better."_

Comment: Point made. Will add this to later posts. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer
it is:
`total_items = sum([i[1] for i in shopping_cart])`
I stored the number in a variable called "total_items" and got the total using the sum function for i.
@IronKey helped me with this answer in my other post.
Hope this helps anyone else with similar issues